# getting coordinates from api and show in google maps

Tags: angular

I need to get the location coordinates from given API and show the area in google maps embedded wihin my page in angular 2.
So far I have done like this
**MapComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from '../shared/DataService';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-maps',
  templateUrl: './maps.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./maps.component.css']
})
export class MapsComponent implements OnInit {
  lat: number;
    lng: number;
  constructor(private location:DataService) { }
loc:any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.location.getDetails().subscribe((data)=>
  {
    this.lat=data.store.location[0];
    this.lng=data.store.location[1];
    console.log(this.lat+" "+this.lng);

  })
  }

}
```

**MapComponent.html**

```
<div class="container">

<sebm-google-map ([latitude])="lat"  ([longitude])="lng">
  <!-- <sebm-google-map-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></sebm-google-map-marker> -->
</sebm-google-map>
</div>
```

However I am just getting blue screen in map zone . When I am changing ([longitude]) to [longitude] then I am getting some city. Please help why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax that is working for you, `[longitude]="lng"` is for one-way data-binding - you are telling angular to take the value in your component's "lng" property, and assign it to the map component's "longitude" input.

The syntax for two-way data-binding would be `[(longitude)]="lng"`

I'm not quite sure what the compiler does with your syntax that doesn't work, i.e. `([longitude])="lng"` (note that you have the round and square braces swapped from what would be valid two-way binding syntax).

For a more detailed explanation, see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#property-binding